# Corona physiscs, check when an object is motionless and its x, y values

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

im new to corona and I would appreciate some help with physics.
I have a box that is created every time you press a button

```
function buttonPress (e)
    local box = display.newRect(xLocation, 70, 50, 50);
    physics.addBody( box, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3 } )
end
```

I want to be able to detect if each one is stationary, and its location. If certain conditions are met then perform an action.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `object.isAwake`, physics objects will **"go to sleep"** when they are not moving or interacting with other physics bodies

```
if box.isAwake then
    print("im awake!") 
else
    print("im asleep") --motionless
end
```

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/isAwake.html